# $.post to php from jquery

Tags: jquery, post

Hi all i have 2 drop down list, when they select i'll get the value to get query to post on php. This is my  var.

```
var id2 = $("#description option:selected").attr('value');

var id3 = $("#page option:selected").attr('value');
```

it is working fine with this code

```
$.post("./includes/select_producprice_n_showpage.php", {id2:id2},
                        function(data1){
                        $("#page").removeAttr("disabled");
                        $("#page").html(data1);
```

now when i tried to use id2 and id3 for `{id2:id3}` $.post i cannot echo id3 but i can see the var in console.log. does it mean it has to be same value like `{id2:id2}`? what would be the work around here? Gigantic thanks.

```
$.post("./includes/select_total.php", {id2:id3},
                        function(data3){
                        $("#total").html(data3);
                        console.log(id2);
                        console.log(id3);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. But if you want to pass both values at the same time you need something like this: `{id2: id2, id3: id3}` (Use better names by the way, you'll thank yourself later)

Comment: @CaptainCarl THANKS!!! Now I'm ready to die. LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to post both id2 and id3. You need to send then like this - `{id2:id2 , id3:id3}`

```
$.post("./includes/select_producprice_n_showpage.php", {id2:id2 , id3:id3},
                        function(data1){
                        $("#page").removeAttr("disabled");
                        $("#page").html(data1);
```

`{id2:id3}` will send `id3` value with parameter name `id2` that is why you cannot echo `id3` as 
 the parameter name is `id2`

Also -  *you can get id2 and id3 in a simple way*

```
var id2 = $("#description").val();
var id3 = $("#page").val();
```